# Calculating Quasi-components

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I'm trying to calculate quasi-components is $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the topology generated by the subbasis $\mathcal{S} = \tau_e \cup \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q}^2) \cup A$ where $\tau_e$ is the euclidean topology, $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q}^2)$ is the power set of $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ and $A=\{(x,y) \cup (U \cap \mathbb{Q}^2) : (x,y) \in U \in \tau_e\}$.

In this topology if $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Q}^2$ then $\{(x,y)\}$ is clopen so its quasi-component must be the sigleton $\{(x,y)\}$. But when $(x,y) \notin \mathbb{Q}^2$ then its quasi-component, $Q(x,y)$ must be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2 - \mathbb{Q}^2$ my guess is that $Q(x,y) = \mathbb{R}^2 - \mathbb{Q}^2$ but I don't know how to show that $\mathbb{R}^2 - \mathbb{Q}^2 \subset Q(x,y)$. I would appreaciate any help.